# Using Object Mapper Model for generating a request

Tags: ios, swift, model, objectmapper

I use classes that imports Object Mapper as my models in my project. I use them to parse the webAPI response.

```
import UIKit
import ObjectMapper

class ReturnModel: Mappable
{
var FilingStatusId : Int?
var FormName : String?
var OrderId : String?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map)
{
    FilingStatusId <- map["FilingStatusId"]
    FormName <- map["FormName"]
    OrderId <- map["OrderId"]
}
}
```

To generate a webAPI request, so far i have been using dictionary. Now i thought i would use the same models to generate the API request.

```
var returnModel: ReturnModel? = nil
returnModel?. FilingStatusId = payerModel?. FilingStatusId
returnModel?. FormName = payerModel?. FormName
returnModel?. OrderId = payerModel?. OrderId
```

But the returnModel has 'nil' even after executing the code.

Comment: Why `nil`? `var returnModel: ReturnModel? = nil`

Comment: if i dont initialise it as nil, it says an error "variable 'returnModel' used before initialisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not intializing the object.

```
var returnModel: ReturnModel? = ReturnModel()
```

You can create a `init` method for this, it will work separately, but with ObjectMapper.

```
init(filingStatusId: Int, formName: String, orderId: String {
    self.FilingStatusId = filingStatusId
    self.FormName = formName
    self.OrderId = orderId
}
```

Then you can create `returnModel` like we normally do:

```
let returnModel = ReturnModel(payerModel?. FilingStatusId, formName: payerModel?. FormName, orderId: OrderId = payerModel?. OrderId )
```

Comment: I couldn't initialize as u said above. The init method inside the model has arguments. It says "Missing argument for parameter 'map' in call"